# How to use Generic Type in NgRx createAction props<>()

Tags: typescript, ngrx

I want to create an NgRx action creator factory. But I don't know how it is possible to pass in a generic type to the `props` method.

```js
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";

function actionFactory<T>(name: string) {
  return createAction(name, props<T>());
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

It throws this error

```
Type 'Props<T>' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): object'
```

How do I need to modify the factory method to pass a generic type into the `props` method like this?:

```js
const action = actionFactory<{ id: string }>("sample");
```

You can try it yourself on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-generic-props?file=index.ts)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `createAction` already is an 'action creator factory'

Comment: I simplified the issue for this question. I actually want to create multiple actions with my custom factory. If it helps I can explain my problem in more detail. But let's assume it is required

Comment: The problem is `NotAllowedCheck` here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/d4894843ae6342d2f9e0b828afb532560db148d4/modules/store/src/models.ts#L80 which determines `T` to be an empty object and thus fails causing the not assignable error. The obvious solution would be to extend T to some type which is not empty, but this doesn't work for some reason. I tried quite a few other things but did not manage to bypass or satisfy this check, other than specifying an actual object in the way it is normally used.

Comment: That's bad news, but thanks for trying!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems `@ngrx/store` - from some reasons - prevents creating actions with empty objects. Here is a possible solution respecting `@ngrx/store` requirements and making actions fully typed:

```
import { createAction, props, Props, NotAllowedCheck } from "@ngrx/store";

// T extends object meets the condition of props function
function actionFactory<T extends object>(name: string) {
  // restricting config type to match createAction requirements
  return createAction(name, props<T>() as Props<T> & NotAllowedCheck<T>);
}

// ok
const action = actionFactory<{ id: string }>("sample");

// empty object picked up on type level
const emptyAction = actionFactory<{}>("sample");
emptyAction({}); // error as expected properly
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-generic-props-fcvrao?file=index.ts)

Comment: nice, I tried similar with extending `T` but was missing the `as Props<T> & NotAllowedCheck<T>` cast.

Answer (score 4):

With NgRx 11, you need to change Props to ActionCreatorProps.

```
return createAction(name, props<T>() as ActionCreatorProps<T> & NotAllowedCheck<T>);
```