# NgRX Using generic type in createAction props

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

before I start, there is [an already same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888508/how-to-use-generic-type-in-ngrx-createaction-props) asked by another fellow, but that seems to be outdated and the answer doesn't solve the problem anymore.

My problem is the same as described in that question. I use `@ngrx/store` version `14.3.0`. I want to create a function that creates action based on the passed parameter. For example:

```js
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export function loadContent<TParams extends object>(key: string) {
    return createAction(
        `[${key}] Load ${key}`,
        props<TParams>()
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    );
}
```

This snipped results in a compiler error as `TParams` doesn't match the type requirements enforced by `props` function. Here is the full error:

```
Error: libs/state/content-primitives/src/lib/content-actions.ts:7:9 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(type: `[${string}] Load ${string}`, config: ActionCreatorProps<TParams> & NotAllowedCheck<TParams>): ActionCreator<`[${string}] Load ${string}`, (props: TParams & NotAllowedCheck<...>) => TParams & TypedAction<...>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams> & NotAllowedCheck<TParams>'.
      Type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' is not assignable to type 'NotAllowedCheck<TParams>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(type: `[${string}] Load ${string}`, creator: Creator<any[], never>): FunctionWithParametersType<any[], object & TypedAction<`[${string}] Load ${string}`>> & TypedAction<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Creator<any[], never>'.
      Type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): never'.

7         props<TParams>()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Error: libs/state/content-primitives/src/lib/content-actions.ts:7:15 - error TS2344: Type 'TParams' does not satisfy the constraint 'NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>'.
  Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>'.

7         props<TParams>()
                ~~~~~~~
```

After this, I tried to match this type parameter exactly the same as defined in the [NgRX source code](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/14.3.0/modules/store/src/action_creator.ts#L128) for `props`. I basically took the generic type definitions and pasted in my code:

```js
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { NotAllowedInPropsCheck } from '@ngrx/store/src/models';

export function loadContent<TParams extends SafeProps, SafeProps = NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>>(key: string) {
    return createAction(
        `[${key}] Load ${key}`,
        props<TParams>()
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    );
}
```

This one also didn't do the trick and failed with the following compilation error:

```
Error: libs/state/content-primitives/src/lib/content-actions.ts:7:9 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(type: `[${string}] Load ${string}`, config: ActionCreatorProps<object> & "action creator cannot return an empty object"): ActionCreator<`[${string}] Load ${string}`, (props: never) => object & TypedAction<...>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionCreatorProps<object> & "action creator cannot return an empty object"'.
      Type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreatorProps<object>'.
        Type 'TParams' is not assignable to type 'object'.
          Type 'SafeProps' is not assignable to type 'object'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(type: `[${string}] Load ${string}`, creator: Creator<any[], never>): FunctionWithParametersType<any[], object & TypedAction<`[${string}] Load ${string}`>> & TypedAction<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Creator<any[], never>'.
      Type 'ActionCreatorProps<TParams>' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): never'.

7         props<TParams>()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  libs/state/content-primitives/src/lib/content-actions.ts:4:56
    4 export function loadContent<TParams extends SafeProps, SafeProps = NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>>(key: string) {
                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This type parameter might need an `extends object` constraint.


Error: libs/state/content-primitives/src/lib/content-actions.ts:7:15 - error TS2344: Type 'TParams' does not satisfy the constraint 'NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>'.
  Type 'SafeProps' is not assignable to type 'NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>'.

7         props<TParams>()
                ~~~~~~~

  libs/state/content-primitives/src/lib/content-actions.ts:4:56
    4 export function loadContent<TParams extends SafeProps, SafeProps = NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>>(key: string) {
                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This type parameter might need an `extends NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>` constraint.
```

The error states that `SafeProps` isn't assignable to type `object`, but I don't understand how can it be as `NotAllowedInPropsCheck<TParams>` generic type checks whether the provided type is an `object`.

Also, how is it possible that the exactly the same generic type formula doesn't apply here. I am looking for a solution that I can make this compile without using `any` type.

Answer (score 3):

NgRx basically enforces having an object with a key as a payload for action. What this means, inside that object, you can have anything, but on the root level you need to have an object with at least one key (no empty objects allowed). Here is a relatively easy fix:

```js
export function loadContent<TParams>(key: string) {
  return createAction(
      `[${key}] Load ${key}`,
      (payload: TParams) => ({payload}),
  );
}

const action = loadContent<number>('Content');

action({payload: 6});
```

If you dislike adding the `payload` key every time when you dispatch the action, you can ditch the `props` function and provide a manual implementation in a simple manner:

```js
export function loadContent<TParams>(key: string) {
  return createAction(
      `[${key}] Load ${key}`,
      (payload: TParams) => ({payload}),
  );
}

const load = loadContent<number>('Content');

load(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a workaround.

I'm not sure about the exact terminology, but add an object with a single parameter as a fallback type.

```
props<TParams | { x: any }>()
```

If a concrete type is provided as an argument to your function (I'm assuming you always will provide one), then it will use it, otherwise it will use the `{ x: any }` type.

This will make the compiler happy.

Comment: This doesn't provide the full type for the action, though? My reducer is complaining saying that nothing from TParams is defined. Only x.

Answer (score 0):

The way I went about this issue is I pass props in. Really the functionality I'm trying to achieve is a guarantee that all actions created using the wrapper has some specific properties.

```
export interface IdKey {
  id: string;
}

export function createIdAction<P extends IdKey>(type: string, props: ActionCreatorProps<P> & NotAllowedCheck<P>) {
  return createAction(
    `[Generic ID Action] ${type}`,
    props
  );
}
```

So when you try to create props without the `id: string` property:

```
const setStatus = createIdAction('Set Status', props<{ readonly status: string; }>);
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Argument of type '() => ActionCreatorProps<{ readonly status: string; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionCreatorProps<IdKey>'
```

The benefit of doing this is that you get the full typing for the action so that your reducers don't complain.